# Simulate JMenuItem MouseListener on JButton

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, mouselistener, jmenuitem

I don't know if title is understandable.
Whatever, I have some JMenuItems, and for these I've set up mouseListener.

```
mntmExtractPaleographyFeature.addMouseListener(this);
```

where *mntmExtractPaleographyFeature* is a JMenuitem and *this* is the class that implements *MouseListener*.

So I've added method for mouseListener like

```
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getSource()==mntmExtractPaleographyFeature) {
        //Code Here
    }
```

Now I have this JButton *extractPaleographyB* that does exact the same thing of the JMenuItem. I don't want to copy/paste code two times (also because It's not the only button/jmenuitem). I've tried with

```
extractPaleographyB.addMouseListener(mntmExtractPaleographyFeature.getMouseListeners()[1]);
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using an ActionListener for the JButton, then having both the MouseListener handler and the ActionListener handler both call the same separate method?

Answer (score 2):

Create an [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and use for both menu item and button

The piece of code from the tutorial

```
Action leftAction = new LeftAction(); //LeftAction code is shown later
...
button = new JButton(leftAction)
...
menuItem = new JMenuItem(leftAction);
```

To create an Action object, you generally create a subclass of AbstractAction and then instantiate it. In your subclass, you must implement the actionPerformed method to react appropriately when the action event occurs. Here's an example of creating and instantiating an AbstractAction subclass:

```
leftAction = new LeftAction("Go left", anIcon,
             "This is the left button.",
             new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_L));
...
class LeftAction extends AbstractAction {
    public LeftAction(String text, ImageIcon icon,
                      String desc, Integer mnemonic) {
        super(text, icon);
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        displayResult("Action for first button/menu item", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: So should I create a class for every button and jMenuItem?

Comment: @AntonioCalì: for every button/menu item that has a unique function. For instance, if I were to create a Calculator class, I would use a single Action class for all my number buttons, since they all do the same basic thing, with the only difference being the number they represent. 1+

Comment: is it a good thing to create class instead using method like mouseListener?

Comment: @AntonioCalì: You seem a little confused -- creating a MouseListener **is** creating a new class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels in the described case the MouseListener is added as **this** so a new instance is not created

Comment: @AntonioCalì why a new instance creation is a problem?

Comment: Yes, I probably misunderstand something. I have my class that implements MouseListener, so I don't create any new class for every action, I just added a if-then statement based on Source Pressed in the OnMouseReleased method.